# Disable specific warnings from cpplint

Tags: c++, linter, cpplint

When running cpplint, I run into some warnings that I'd like to completely disable. Specifically the copyright message & whitespaces:

> range.h:0:  No copyright message found.  You should have a line:
>
> "Copyright [year] "  [legal/copyright] [5]
>
> range.h:10:  At least two spaces is best between code and comments
>
> [whitespace/comments] [2]

How do I accomplish this? Ideally would be modifying the CPPLINT.cfg file, but I would take an inline comment or a command line flag. I can't find any documentation on disabling rules.

Comment: It looks like there's some mechanism for disabling rules, but again I don't see any documentation =/ https://github.com/google/styleguide/blob/gh-pages/cpplint/cpplint.py#L603

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude no I clearly just linked a line to the source code without trying to understand it. cpplint --help word vomits 180 lines of stuff. And yes, I did try that. Somehow I missed it. It happens. Your rush to judgement is pretty unkind, in my opinion. You might consider trying to be inclusive in your responses.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can configure filters in `CPPLINT.cfg`:

```
filter=-whitespace,-legal/copyright
```

Comment: For anyone trying to work out where to get the list of filters, the commandline usgae message says: To see a list of all the categories used in cpplint, pass no arg: `cpplint --filter=`

Comment: Is there a way to specify filters via a comment at the top of the file so they are in effect throughout that whole file? We get tons of lint errors from using some 3rd party macros, e.g. `MATCHER_P` from Google Mock.